# Stop screen changing when using HDMI Switch on PC?

Tags: video, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a HDMI Switch which has both my Xbox and PC going into it.
I also have another screen which is only my PC on DVI

When I use my PC I use the dual screen setup and it works fine
However when I change my switcher to the xbox I loose connection on the PC HDMI and it resorts to one screen, messing up my layout

I managed to do a temporary fix by putting a converter between the PC and the switcher, so the PC thinks there is a device connected even when its not selected on the switcher

I was wondering if there is a way to force the PC to output to HDMI even when its not connected,

Hope this all makes sense
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the switch is physically switching the power to the HDMI output away from the computer, making the PC think you have unplugged the screen.  Unfortunately, this is a design feature of the switch you're using and there's not much you can do about it except using that converter you have.

Comment: Thats what I assumed.
I was just wondering if there was a software way to stop this happening?

Comment: Nope. It's one of the most annoying things about Windows. The Internet is littered with people trying to disable it without success. It's so ridiculous that people are actually selling "monitor detection killer" devices which you shove into the HDMI port to stop it from happening, which is basically what your converter is doing.

Comment: It's a Windows issue.   I have a Macbook on the second input, and it behaves completely differently, always preserving the configured size for the second display.